# value pushed to array won't stay

Tags: javascript

I want to push a value to the end of an array but it is not working for some reason.  When I click the button it should add the value to the end of the array.  Then if I click it again it should tell me that it is still there but instead it just keeps pushin to the array.  How can I get the value to stay in the array.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var asdf = ["a","b","c","e"];
                if (asdf.indexOf("d")==-1) {
                    asdf.push("d");
                    alert(asdf.indexOf("d")+"It has been pushed to the end.");
                } else {
                    alert(asdf.indexOf("d")+"It is still there.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call myFunction, your array `asdf` is built again from scratch.

Something like this would work:

```
var myFunction = (function () {
    // This line is only run once.
    var asdf = ["a", "b", "c", "e"];

    // This is run with every call to myFunction, and will reuse the array
    return function () {
        if (asdf.indexOf("d") == -1) {
            asdf.push("d");
            alert(asdf.indexOf("d") + "It has been pushed to the end.");
        } else {
            alert(asdf.indexOf("d") + "It is still there.");
        }

    };

}());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're declaring `asdf` locally inside the function. So when the function is finished, the `asdf` variable is deleted, and then re-created next time you click the button. Instead you need to make it global:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.asdf = ["a","b","c","e"];
        function myFunction() {
            if (window.asdf.indexOf("d")==-1) {
                window.asdf.push("d");
                alert(window.asdf.indexOf("d")+"It has been pushed to the end.");
            } else {
                alert(window.asdf.indexOf("d")+"It is still there.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While that works, using a global variable is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - I agree entirely, my answer assumes the simple case provided. Any solution is going to revolve around a basis of variables being global though since the state of the variable needs to be maintained outside the function.

Comment: Check my answer for a common pattern to create static variables in JavaScript.  It is a clean solution that doesn't use a global.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Yeah I saw that. Interesting solution, although I dislike statics almost as much as I dislike globals :P

Comment: Then think of them as private.  In this case, it is the same thing.